# vmin, vmax not changing the display range in plt.imshow ( iPython notebook)

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, imshow, imread

I'm doing some manipulation with images and need the image to be displayed correctly exactly as it is in the array. For some reason when I display image in iPython, they get modified. All solutions to this issue involve changing vmin and vmax to appropriate values, but for some reason they don't affect my image at all.

As you can see from the images, only the very first one is displayed as is. The rest of them have bizarre colors and changing the type or dynamic range with vmin and vmax does not seem to affect the output.

Here's my code:

```
image_files = os.listdir(all_folders[1])
im=os.path.join(all_folders[1], image_files[1])

plt.imshow(ndimage.imread(im))
plt.show()
plt.imshow(ndimage.imread(im).astype(int))
plt.show()
plt.imshow(ndimage.imread(im).astype(float))
plt.show()
plt.imshow(ndimage.imread(im).astype(int),vmin=0,vmax=255)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(ndimage.imread(im).astype(int),vmin=0,vmax=10)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(ndimage.imread(im).astype(int),vmin=0,vmax=1)
plt.show()
```

And here are the images I get:

[Results: first three image displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVMwD.jpg)

[Results: next three images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6DrV.jpg)

Comment: What is the shape if your input image?  I suspect you also want to pass the `interpolation='none'` kwarg to `imshow`.

Comment: It's 15 by 31 pixels. I have tried the interpolation = 'none' as well. It unsmoothes the image but the colors stay the same.

Comment: what is `im.shape`

Comment: That means mpl is treating them as RGB images.  Do you intend for these to be color images read in?

Comment: Yes, I want them to be color.

Comment: Make sure they are uint8 with gamut [0, 255] or float with gamut [0, 1] http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow

Comment: Is it possible to have a different gamut for example for uint8? I try vmin=0, vmax=50, for uint8 but I still get the result as if it was [0,255].

Comment: The vmin and vmax are used for scaler images (`im.ndim == 2`) and control the normalization.  You have rgb images (`im.ndim == 3`) which are not normalized internally (hence vmin and vmax have no effect).  The gamuts are on your _input_.

Comment: Werid, matlab has nor problem with ndim==3. Is it possible to change gamut for RGB image at all in any other way? It seems strange that there wouldn't be a way to do that.